# Что делать при ошибке aiogram: Wrong http url specified?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

При изменении медиа-файла столкнулся с ошибкой `aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong http url specified`

Код:

```
photo1 = types.InputMediaPhoto('avatar/photos/file_8.jpg')
await bot.edit_message_media(media=photo1, chat_id=call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
```

Весь текст ошибки:

```
!ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: exception=BadRequest('Wrong http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testsearchanon\main.py", line 800, in oz1
    await bot.edit_message_media(media=photo1, chat_id=call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 2743, in edit_message_media
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.EDIT_MESSAGE_MEDIA, payload, files)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong http url specified
```

Из-за чего возникает эта ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю невозможно редактировать сообщения если тип контента отличается. То есть был текст - пытаемся поменять на фото - ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ или было аудио - попытка менять на видео - ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ и тд. То есть можно редактировать только фото на другое фото.
Вот немного текста из [офф документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/edit_message_media.html)

> Use this method to edit animation, audio, document, photo, or video
> messages. If a message is part of a message album, then it can be
> edited only to an audio for audio albums, only to a document for
> document albums and to a photo or a video otherwise. When an inline
> message is edited, a new file can’t be uploaded; use a previously
> uploaded file via its file_id or specify a URL. On success, if the
> edited message is not an inline message, the edited
> aiogram.types.message.Message is returned, otherwise True is returned.

Примерный перевод.

> Используйте этот метод для редактирования анимации, аудио, документа,
> фото или видео сообщений. Если сообщение является частью альбома
> сообщений, то его можно редактировать только до аудио для
> аудиоальбомов, только до документа для альбомов документов и до фото
> или видео в противном случае. При редактировании встроенного сообщения
> нельзя загрузить новый файл; используйте ранее загруженный файл по его
> file_id или укажите URL. В случае успеха, если редактируемое сообщение
> не является встроенным сообщением, возвращается отредактированное
> сообщение aiogram.types.message.Message, в противном случае
> возвращается True.

Как вариант решения это удалить предыдущее сообщение и отослать новое.

Comment: неа, вы не правы. Проблема заключается в том, что вместо файла надо использовать url картинки :)

Comment: Эхх, ну так задача была какая? Впихнуть файл с диска в то, нет? Ну не суть, покажите хоть как вы это сделали.